# CookieError: Illegal key value

Tags: python, cookies, web.py

I use [web.py](http://webpy.org), which internally uses the [`cookie.SimpleCookie`](http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html#Cookie.SimpleCookie) class to load cookies incoming from the user's browser.

Occasionally, I get exceptions like:

```
...
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/Cookie.py", line 455, in set
    raise CookieError("Illegal key value: %s" % key)
CookieError: Illegal key value: SinaRot/g/news.sina.com.cn
```

The offending character seems to be the forward slash (`/`), which, according to my reading of  [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) (cookies) and [RFC 2068](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt) (HTTP 1.1) should be disallowed, so that's OK.

I don't set this cookie, and I'm not sure why or how it got set for my domain (a proxy, perhaps?), but that's irrelevant; the larger issue is that simplecookie fails hard when it encounters this cookie, and returns an error to the user.

So, my question is: is there any way to ask `SimpleCookie` to simply ignore cookies that are invalid, but return the rest? I couldn't find anything obvious in the docs to do this.

Comment: Can't you just catch the CookieError exception?

Comment: I can (and should), but because it's an exception, I can't access the other cookies, including our session cookie. And subsequent requests will still contain the same cookie that caused the error. Furthermore, if it is coming from a proxy, attempting to unset it will likely be in vain, as the proxy will just re-set it the next time around.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
def get_cookies():
    import Cookie
    ans = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    for bit in os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE', '').split('; '):
        try:
            ans.load(bit)
        except Cookie.CookieError:
            pass
    return ans
```

Answer (score 2):

When setting cookie name, you should not add space. If there is space in the cookie name, or any space in quotes of the cookie name, it will send you `CookieError: Illegal key value`

Answer (score 0):

My webpy app has experienced `CookieError: Illegal key value: )|utmcmd` set by Google Analytics in Firefox browser. To fix it I issue redirect trying to set correct value.

```
def myinternalerror(): 
    try: 
        web.cookies() 
    except CookieError: 
        if not "cookie_err" in web.input(): 
            web.setcookie("__utmz", None, domain=web.ctx.host) 
            raise web.seeother(web.changequery(cookie_err=1)) 
    return web.internalerror(render.site.e500()) 

if not web.config.debug:
    app.internalerror = myinternalerror
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me, because attempting to set a cookie whose name is illegal will still throw the cookie error. This in turn does not delete the cookie, and the problem comes back next time.

Comment: Does the name or value of the cookie have illegal characters? In my case it is the value, so I reset it with correct value and redirect back to the same URL — so incorrect cookie gets fixed.

Comment: I think the forward slashes are illegal. Every browser I've inserted this cookie into works fine, but the `Cookie` module seems to be more pedantic than browsers.